# What are the possible ways of setting custom baud rates for serial ports in Linux user mode and kernel mode?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What are the possible ways of setting custom baud rates for serial ports in Linux user mode and kernel mode?

I see TCGETS2/TCSETS2 ioctl calls to achieve this. Is it possible to set custom baud rates without any special ioctls?

Comment: `without any special ioctls` - so with what? [tcsetattr](https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcsetattr) also calls [ioctl](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/tcsetattr.c#L78).

Comment: I mean without TIOCGSERIAL/TIOCSSERIAL and TCGETS2/TCSETS2 ioctls

Comment: The `setserial` system utility uses `TIOCGSERIAL` and `TIOCSSERIAL`. I don't know if any system utilities use `TCGETS2` and `TCSETS2` but `libserialport` uses them (but `libserialport` doesn't use `TIOCGSERIAL` and `TIOCSSERIAL`).

Comment: In general answer is “no”. If some old drivers provide custom ABI, then it is possible, but when you find such — tell me, it would be good to deprecate that nonsense.

Comment: to keep it simple, the baud rate can be set with the function: `cfsetospeed(&settings, baud); /* baud rate */`

Comment: This question lacks a point - what is your *actual goal* for which the usual methods are unsuitable?  Or are you trying to audit something?   You can always put printk's in the actual hardware driver that modifies the UART settings...